# I just learned about dynamic memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to prevent memory leak as It dynamically allocate and delete properly for his homework. My homework code (large) didn't work. 
So I made small example code to understand better, but it doesn't work neither.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=5;
class son;
class dau;

class papa
{
public:
    papa(int pair);
    void show();
    int pair();
    void allocate(int howmanyeach);

private:
    son *sonpnt[MAX];
    dau *daupnt[MAX];
    int m_pair;

};

class son
{
public:
    son(int don);
    int money();

private:
    int m_money=0;        
};

class dau
{
public:
    dau(int don);
    int money();

private:
    int m_money=0;    
};

//////////////////////////////////////////

papa::papa(int pair)
{
    m_pair=pair;
}

int papa::pair()
{
    return m_pair;
}

void papa:: allocate(int howmanyeach)
{
    if( howmanyeach > MAX || howmanyeach<1)
        cout<<"impossible"<<endl;
    else
        for(int i=0; i<howmanyeach; i++)
        {
            sonpnt[i]=new son(7);
            daupnt[i]=new dau(5);
        }
}

void papa::show()
{
    for(int i=0;i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(sonpnt[i]!=nullptr)
            cout<<sonpnt[i]->money();
    }
    cout<<'\n';

    for(int i=0;i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(daupnt[i]!=nullptr)
            cout<<daupnt[i]->money();
    }        
}

son::son(int don)
{
    m_money+=don;
}

int son::money()
{
    return m_money;
}

dau::dau(int don)
{
    m_money+=don;
}

int dau::money()
{
    return m_money;
}

/////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    papa p(5);
    p.allocate(1);
    p.show();   
}
```

It can be helpful if you can point it out
Also, any advice about my main project would be helpful. I have three classes that I need to get things from each others. It's a game. player, monster, field are the classes. I am not allowed to touch class public interfaces. The challenge is thatcI need to new and delete properly with a private member m_pointer and a private member array of pointers m_monster,which has its size some global const like MAX. I think, except the challenge, my code seems ok. This dynamic thingy I just learned is the bummer. I want to at least try my small case code properly. What should be tried on this code?

Thanks

Comment: `son *sonpnt[MAX];` declares an array of pointers of *indeterminate* value - they are not `nullptr` by default, you need to initialize that explicitly (e.g.: `son *sonpnt[MAX] = {};`)

Comment: Your program does not have a user-defined destructor for `papa`, so even if you initialized all of those pointers correctly, you still have memory leaks.  The way you should set up your class is to have 1) A copy constructor, 2) An assignment operator, 3) A destructor  4) A way to fill the object with test data.  That's it, nothing else.  Then you implement all four.  Partial implementations of dynamic memory handling isn't going to give you the desired results.

Comment: When you allocate in `allocate()`, store the `howmanyeach` internally in the papa `class` so that you know how many you have allocated. Also, `papa` needs a destructor to release the dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and enable all warnings and debug info when compiling. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Read [*more about C++*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone here! I could not find these in the document I probably need more skills to navigate it better. My project now works pretty good! But it could be just superficial. Do you know how to check memory leakage?

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you should delete dynamically allocated objects of papa in it's destructor. As you might know, C++ provides default constructor for each class but it doesn't include dynamically allocated pointers. You should add a destructor:

```
papa::~papa()
{
    for(int i=0;i<MAX; i++)
    {
        delete sonpnt[i];
        delete daupnt[i];
    }   
}
```

I would have changed the constructor as well to explicitly initialize these pointers to null ptr:

```
papa::papa(int pair)
{
  for(int i=0;i<MAX; i++)
  {
    sonpnt[i] = nullptr;
    daupnt[i] = nullptr;
  }
    m_pair=pair;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. They are all I needed.